# Any reason not to use `new object().foo()`?

Tags: c#, java, new-operator

When using extremely short-lived objects that I only need to call one method on, I'm inclined to chain the method call directly to `new`. A very common example of this is something like the following:

```
string noNewlines = new Regex("\\n+").Replace(" ", oldString);
```

The point here is that I have no need for the `Regex` object after I've done the one replacement, and I like to be able to express this as a one-liner. Is there any non-obvious problem with this idiom? Some of my coworkers have expressed discomfort with it, but without anything that seemed to be like a good reason.

(I've marked this as both C# and Java, since the above idiom is common and usable in both languages.)

Comment: Only reason I wouldnt do this is if the `new object()` implements `IDisposable`.  Clearly `Regex` does not so looks fine to me.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 - Should have put that as an answer!

Comment: @Reddog - Should have :)

Comment: @SwDevMan81 The *only* reason? What about if there is a [larger] chain that may (for awesome design reasons) return null as an intermediate expression? ;-)

Comment: @pst - Haha true, then I would hope my awesome error handling would alert me of the issue :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular pattern is fine -- I use it myself on occasion.

But I would not use this pattern as you have in your example.  There are two alternate approaches that are better.

**Better approach:** Use the static method [Regex.Replace(string,string,string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx).  There is no reason to obfuscate your meaning with the `new`-style syntax when a static method is available that does the same thing.

**Best approach:** If you use the same static (not dynamically-generated) Regex from the same method, and you call this method a lot, you should store the Regex object as a private static field on the class containing the method, since this avoids parsing the expression on each call to the method.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked the fact that there's a static method that does this very thing. As for your second point, this is a seldom-called function, or else I *would* have moved the regex into a member variable to avoid recreating it repeatedly.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything wrong with this; I do this quite frequently myself.

The only exception to the rule might be for debugging purposes, it's sometimes necessary to be able to see the state of the object in the debugger, which can be difficult in a one-liner like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the object afterwards, I don't see a problem - I do it myself from time to time as well. However, it can be quite hard to spot, so if your coworkers are expressing discomfort, you might need to put it into a variable so there are no hard feelings on the team. Doesn't really hurt you.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to be careful when you're chaining methods of objects that implement `IDisposable`. Doing a single-line chain doesn't really leave room for calling Dispose or the using {...} block.

For example:

```
DialogResult result = New SomeCfgDialog(some_data).ShowDialog();
```

There is no instance variable on which to call Dispose.

Then there is potential to obfuscate intent, hurt rather than improve readability and make it tougher to examine values while debugging. But those are all issues particular to the object and the situation and the number of methods chained. I don't think that there is a single reason to avoid it. Sometimes doing this will make the code more concise and readable and other times it might hurt for some of the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're sure that the object is never needed again (or you're not creating multiple instances of an identical object), then there's no problem with it.

If the rest of your team isn't comfortable with it, though, you might want to re-think the decision. The team should set the standards and you should follow them. Be consistent. If you want to change the standard, discuss it. If they don't agree, then fall in line.

Answer (score 1):

I think thats ok, and would welcome comments/reasons to the contrary.  When the object is not short lived (or uses unmanaged resources - ie COM) then this practice can get you into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is readability.

Putting the "chained" methods on a separate line seems to be the preferred convention with my team.

```
string noNewlines = new Regex("\\n+")
                             .Replace(" ", oldString);
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason to avoid this style is that your coworkers might want to inspect the object in a debug mode. If you compound the similar instantiation the readability goes down a lot. For example :

```
String val = new Object1("Hello").doSomething(new Object2("interesting").withThis("input"));
```

Generally I prefer using a static method for the specific example you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem I could see is - if, for some reason, new Regex were NULL because it was not instantiated correctly, you would get a Null Pointer Exception. However, I highly doubt that since Regex is always defined...

Comment: The only way a constructor can fail is to throw an exception, and this will be propagated upwards, interrupting execution.  A constructor will *never* return null.  (Constructors don't actually return anything anyway...)

Comment: `new X(...)` can never evaluate to `null` -- it may throw an Exception. However, you do have a point in that a `null` *anywhere* (else) in a "chained" expression can lead to a hard-to-find NPE (as the stack-trace only points to the line, not the offending expression): `foo().returnsnullsometimes().bar() // aww, crum`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the object you invoke the method on, that's a sign that the method should probably be static.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I'd probably write an extension method to wrap the regex, so that I could write

```
string noNewlines = oldString.RemoveNewlines();
```

The extension method would look something like

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Extensions
{
    static class SystemStringExtensions
    {
        public static string RemoveNewlines(this string inputString)
        {
            // replace newline characters with spaces
            return Regex.Replace(inputString, "\\n+", " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I find this much easier to read than your original example.  It's also quite reusable, as stripping newline characters is one of the more common activities.